# como autorizar edicion de googlesheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

soy nuevo en google apps scritps. Quisiera automatizar una tarea y no se por donde comenzar.

Tengo una planilla con las siguientes columnas:
nombre - Email - fecha de alta - enlace a otra planilla

Y otra planilla que es un template que debo copiar para cada registro, cada vez que ingrese un nuevo Nombre e Email .

Quiero que cuando se ingrese un nuevo registro con nombre e email, automáticamente se cree la fecha de hoy y se cree una copia del template (luego hare modificaciones en esta nueva copia) y se inserte en enlace a esta nueva planilla.

También quisiera enviarle el enlace al nuevo email y darle permisos de edición sobre esta planilla.

Preguntas:

1. -Cómo disparo el evento para que al ingresar un nombre y un email inicie el proceso de copia? Debería poner un botón, cómo?
2. -Cómo realizo una copia del template y obtengo el enlace a este
   nuevo archivo?
3. -Cómo autorizo al destinatario a editar la nueva copia?

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Aunque ya has respondido tu propia pregunta aún la puedes mejorar, por ejemplo, las preguntas deben ser específicas por lo que usualmente no es conveniente incluir varias preguntas, aunque sean retóricas, en una publicación. Las preguntas que incluyen brevemente lo que se ha intentado, buscado e investigado usualmente son bien recibidas y tiene buenas respuestas. Ref. [ask]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

después de mucho investigar aquí esta el resultado.

Espero que a alguien le sirva:

1-En lugar de un boton puse una imagen y asocie la funcion al clickear la imagen se ejecuta el código.

2-copia del template a nuevo archivo

```
  var databaseSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Database');
  var mainSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Main');

  
  // Sheet IDs are found in the url after "/d/"
  var masterID = '...gT3KQZM3q0';
  var templateID = '...h9mhqQlnZ4';
  
  var masterSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(masterID);
  var templateSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(templateID);
  
  // Verify data
  
  if(mainSheet.getRange('B6').isBlank() || mainSheet.getRange('B7').isBlank() || mainSheet.getRange('B8').isBlank()){
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Name, Email and Date of Bith is required to add a new patient to the database'); 
    return;
  }
  // Set new file name 
  var spreadsheetName = "*********** " + mainSheet.getRange('B6').getValue();

  // Copy template
  var templateCopy = DriveApp.getFileById(templateSheet.getId()).makeCopy(spreadsheetName);
```

3- Autorizar a editar el nuevo archivo a un usuario por mail

```
  // send file to patient
  DriveApp.getFileById(templateCopy.getId()).addEditor(mainSheet.getRange('B7').getValue());
```